# Detecting a Pixelated Component of an Image Python

Tags: python, image-processing, blur, pixelate

I was wondering whether anyone was aware of any approaches to discover ***which portion of an image was pixelated.*** For example for the following saussage dog where I have applied the following code

```
img = cv2.imread("sausage.jpg")
blurred_img = cv2.blur(img, (21, 21), 0)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (200, 100), 100, [255, 255, 255], -1)
out = np.where(mask==[255, 255, 255], blurred_img,img)
```

I would like to zoom in to a circle centered at 200,100 with a radius of 100.

[image: Saussage Dog with Pixelated Face]

I have tried looking at edges, but this doesn't give anything definitive and I haven't got an algorithm to extract the information yet.

[image]

Comment: is it only one portion? or you you might have more than one? is it always a circle? or it might have another shape (rectangle, square ...) ??

Comment: Let us just assume it is one portion, it might not be a circle.